# Using gaussian blur with zero size kernel?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I was reading about [Gaussian Blur](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaabe8c836e97159a9193fb0b11ac52cf1) when one of the examples I came across was as follows:

```
cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (0,0), 5)
```

What does `0,0` mean here? This is in sharp contrast to another example I read:

```
cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
```

How are both different from each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight from the documentation:

> Gaussian kernel size. ksize.width and ksize.height can differ but they
>   both must be positive and odd. Or, they can be zero's and then they
>   are computed from sigma.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaabe8c836e97159a9193fb0b11ac52cf1

Comment: Could you explain what does`sigma` do?

Comment: You have two parameters to control sigma - sigmaX (required) and sigmaY (optional). sigmaX and sigmaY represent the Gaussian Kernel standard deviation in their respective x and y directions. This is also straight from the documentation. In a nutshell, the larger you make the standard deviation, the more blurry the image gets.